Sum of cubes < cubes of sum
I know this question is either extremally trivial or an open math problem, but after a quick research couldn't find anything on internet nor with chatgpt, and I'm on a strict deadline for a project.
Is there a theorem that states:
$\sum_i^n( k_i^3) < (\sum_i^n k_i)^3 \qquad n \in ]1; \inf [ \qquad k_i \in N^+$?
How is it called?

Did you try to expand the RHS? Start for example with the case $n=2$

Also, for what it's worth, I would not trust ChatGPT with mathematical proofs of any kind.

ChatGPT couldn't find anything? Hard to believe but very good.
